# How to use a non-JDBC connector in a custom Policy Information Point (PIP)

Tags: wso2, authorization, xacml, openstack4j, wso2-identity-server

I want my custom Policy Information Point (PIP) to be able to connect to [OpenStack Swift](https://docs.openstack.org/swift/latest/) (an Object Storage application) thanks to [this connector](http://www.openstack4j.com/learn/objectstorage). The connector is able to retrieve metadata from an object, which would be sent  back to the Policy Decision Point (PDP) when the right `AttributeId` is requested.
In our context, Swift holds information about our resources (objects here).

Below are all the steps I followed to try and use this connector in my custom PIP.

I got the connector to work locally (no integration with WSO2IS yet) following only the first 3 steps and calling the `swift_test` function in a debug-purposed main class.

1. I followed [this guide](https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS570/Writing+a+Custom+Policy+Info+Point) to implement a custom PIP, which suggests using a database offering a JDBC driver (such as mariadb). My issue is that Swift does not offer a JDBC driver, hence the use of the openstack4j connector.
2. I added the needed openstack4j dependency to the maven project linked in the guide ([here](https://svn.wso2.org/repos/wso2/people/asela/xacml/pip/jdbc/)).
3. I also added the following imports to the extended class (named KMarketJDBCAttributeFinder in the guide):

```
package org.xacmlinfo.xacml.pip.jdbc;

import org.openstack4j.api.OSClient.OSClientV3;
import org.openstack4j.model.common.Identifier;
import org.openstack4j.model.storage.object.SwiftAccount;
import org.openstack4j.model.storage.object.SwiftContainer;
import org.openstack4j.model.storage.object.SwiftObject;
import org.openstack4j.model.storage.object.options.ObjectListOptions;
import org.openstack4j.openstack.OSFactory;

import org.wso2.carbon.identity.entitlement.pip.AbstractPIPAttributeFinder;
...
```

and this function to test and retrieve an object's metadata:

```
public void swift_test() {
  OSClientV3 os = OSFactory.builderV3()
    .endpoint(our_keystoneV3_url)
    .credentials(our_keystone_username, password, domain_identifier)
    .scopeToProject(Identifier.byName(our_tenant), Identifier.byName(our_domain))
    .authenticate();

  SwiftAccount account = os.objectStorage.account().get();
  Map<String, String> md = 
  os.objectStorage.objects().getMetadata("our_container", "our_object");
  System.out.println(md.toString());
}
```

which I call in the overriden `getAttributeValues` of the custom PIP class.

4. I then built the class using `mvn package` to generate the `.jar` which I copied in `<IS_HOME>/repository/components/lib`.
5. I downloaded all my dependencies using `mvn dependency:copy-dependencies`, and copied them all to the same `<IS_HOME>/repository/components/lib` folder.
6. I start the wso2is server, send a XACML request which involves calling my custom PIP, and see the following error in `<IS_HOME>/repository/logs/wso2carbon.log`:

```
ERROR {org.openstack4j.core.transport.internal.HttpExecutor} - No OpenStack4j connector found in classpath
ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.identity.entitlement.pip.CarbonAttributeFinder} - Error while retrieving attribute values from PIP attribute finder: org.openstack4j.api.exceptions.ConnectorNotFoundException: No OpenStack4j connector found in classpath
ERROR {org.wso2.balana.finder.AttributeFinder} - Error while trying to resolve values: Error while retrieving attribute values from PIP attribute finder: No OpenStack4j connector found in classpath
```

Our wso2is server, version 5.7.0 runs on a CentOS 7.6 VM.

My question is then: can we use this kind of connector in a custom PIP with wso2is? If so, how would I go about resolving the classpath issues between my dependencies?

P.S. : I previously added another custom PIP, connecting this time to a MariaDB database which is working well. The `.jar` I create when using `mvn package` contains both custom PIPs, and they are both recognized in the section "PDP > Extension" in the wso2is web interface.

Here is the list of dependencies obtained with the mvn command:

```
activation-1.1.1.jar
btf-1.2.jar
classworlds-1.1-alpha-2.jar
commons-codec-1.9.jar
commons-io-2.3.jar
commons-lang-2.6.jar
commons-logging-1.2.jar
guava-20.0.jar
httpclient-4.5.3.jar
httpcore-4.4.6.jar
jackson-annotations-2.7.0.jar
jackson-core-2.7.3.jar
jackson-core-asl-1.9.7.jar
jackson-coreutils-1.6.jar
jackson-databind-2.7.3.jar
jackson-dataformat-yaml-2.7.3.jar
jackson-jaxrs-base-2.7.3.jar
jackson-jaxrs-json-provider-2.7.3.jar
jackson-mapper-asl-1.9.7.jar
jackson-module-jaxb-annotations-2.7.3.jar
jboss-annotations-api_1.2_spec-1.0.0.Final.jar
jboss-jaxrs-api_2.0_spec-1.0.1.Beta1.jar
jboss-logging-3.3.0.Final.jar
jcip-annotations-1.0.jar
jcl-over-slf4j-1.7.2.jar
jdom2-2.0.6.jar
joss-0.10.2.jar
json-patch-1.9.jar
jsr305-2.0.0.jar
junit-3.8.1.jar
maven-artifact-2.0.jar
maven-compiler-plugin-2.0.jar
maven-plugin-api-2.0.jar
msg-simple-1.1.jar
openstack4j-3.1.0.jar
openstack4j-core-3.1.0.jar
openstack4j-resteasy-3.1.0.jar
org.wso2.carbon.identity.entitlement-4.2.0.jar
plexus-compiler-api-1.5.1.jar
plexus-compiler-javac-1.5.1.jar
plexus-compiler-manager-1.5.1.jar
plexus-container-default-1.0-alpha-8.jar
plexus-utils-1.0.4.jar
resteasy-client-3.1.4.Final.jar
resteasy-jaxrs-3.1.4.Final.jar
resteasy-jaxrs-services-3.1.4.Final.jar
slf4j-api-1.7.2.jar
snakeyaml-1.15.jar
```

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: Hello, you can find the errors I got right in step 6. in the post

Comment: Make sure you have a connector on your classpath.

Comment: How would I go about modifying the classpath within the wso2is application?

Comment: please share at least 1 full stack trace to see `caused by` section. also share the list of libraries you copied to `components/lib` folder

Comment: I added the list of libraries in the question. I don't see anything else than the errors I copied from the log file in relation with my issue though